# Simple Corona SDK based example - can not subscribe through pubnub console

Tags: lua, coronasdk, pubnub

I am attempting to run the default pubnub Helloworld example using Corona. The corona sdk program runs fine in the simulator but I can not see the output in the pubnub console for some reason.  Here is the source for the pubnub Corona SDK.

```
require "pubnub"

multiplayer = pubnub.new({
    publish_key   = "my_publish_key",
    subscribe_key = "my_subscribe_key",
    secret_key    = nil,
    ssl           = nil,
    origin        = "pubsub.pubnub.com"
})

multiplayer:subscribe({
    channel  = "hello-world-corona",
    callback = function(message)
      print(message.msgtext)
    end,
    errorback = function()
      print("Oh no!!! Dropped 3G Conection!")
    end
})

function send_a_message(text)
  multiplayer:publish({
     channel = "hello-world-corona",
     message = { msgtext = text }
   })
end

function send_hello_world()
  send_a_message("Hello World!!!")
end

timer.performWithDelay( 500, send_hello_world, 10 )
send_hello_world()
```

I am using the pubnub provided subscribe and publish keys

To create the API key I used these libraries from pubnub:
https://github.com/pubnub/lua

The problem is that when I build the APK for Android and run it, I can not see the messages on the pubsub console at http://www.pubsub.com/console.  I use the given subscribe and publish keys but see nothing.   I was getting a run time error for internet permission but then changed my build.settings to the following and no longer get a run time error:

build.settings:

```
   settings =
{ 
android =
   {
    permissions =
        {
            { name = ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE", protectionLevel = "signature" },
        },
        usesPermissions =
        {
           -- Required by the MapView to fetch its contents from the Google Maps 
           --servers.
            "android.permission.INTERNET",
            "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS",
            "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
            "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE",
            ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE",


          -- Optional permission used to display current location via the GPS.
            "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",

          -- Optional permission used to display current location via WiFi or 
          -- cellular   
          -- service.
          "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
      },
      usesFeatures =
      {
          -- If you set permissions "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and 
          --"ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" above, then you may want to set up 
          --your app to not require location services as follows.
          -- Otherwise, devices that do not have location sevices (such as a GPS) will 
          -- be unable
          -- to purchase this app in the app store.
            { name = "android.hardware.location", required = false },
            { name = "android.hardware.location.gps", required = false },
            { name = "android.hardware.location.network", required = false },
        },
   }, 
}
```

Comment: Note, I also can not see the messages when running from the Corona Simulator.  Not sure I should be able to?

Answer (score 0):

Please add success and error callbacks, and let us know in your question what you get, and whether its from the success or error callback.

Examples of implementing the success and error callbacks can be found https://github.com/pubnub/lua/blob/master/corona/examples/example-publish/main.lua#L29

geremy

Comment: The app works fine, publishing to the chat app above as long as I use the subscribe_key = "demo" and the publish_key="demo".  When I put in my keys in the Corona Button app, no data is received in the chat app. Everything executes perfectly.

Comment: Very strange. Do you mind contacting us at support@pubnub.com so we can isolate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Corona SDK Debugging Publish Events

Make sure to register the `error` callback to detect problems with your publish call events.  Here is an example of a fully featured **`pubnub.publish({...})`** call.

```
-- 
-- CALL PUBLISH FUNCTION
--
function publish( channel, text )
    pubnub_obj:publish({
        channel  = channel,
        message  = text,
        callback = textout,
        error    = textout
    })
end
```

### Full Lua Publish Demo Example:

Use this to test your lua corona app for publishing messages successfully.  You will see text output for debugging your code.

```
--
-- PubNub : Publish Example
--

require "pubnub"
require "PubnubUtil"

textout = PubnubUtil.textout

--
-- INITIALIZE PUBNUB STATE
--
pubnub_obj = pubnub.new({
    publish_key   = "demo",
    subscribe_key = "demo",
    secret_key    = nil,
    ssl           = nil,
    origin        = "pubsub.pubnub.com"
})

-- 
-- HIDE STATUS BAR
-- 
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- 
-- CALL PUBLISH FUNCTION
--
function publish(channel, text)
    pubnub_obj:publish({
        channel = channel,
        message = text,
        callback = function(r) --textout(r) 
        end,
        error = function(r) textout(r) 
        end
    })
end

-- 
-- MAIN TEST
-- 
local my_channel = 'lua-dsm'

--
-- Publish String
--
publish("abcd", 'Hello World!' )

--
-- Publish Dictionary Object
--
publish("efgh", { Name = 'John', Age = '25' })

--
-- Publish Array
--
publish("ijkl", { 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday' })
```

Check out publishing messages with [JavaScript Publish API Reference](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#publish) in our Documents page.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure where I would see the messages. When I run it on an Android I don't see any messages at all.  When I run it in the simulator I don't see anything as the app just publishes data but displays nothing to screen.  Am I correct in assuming I should be able to read the messages sent from the Android app from within the pubnub console at pubnub.com/console?  Sent a screen shot of the console to support@pubnub.com.

Comment: Check the definition of **`textout`** or Change the definition of this function to print the output location.